# How to translate a nested, piped bash command to child_process.spawn

Tags: node.js

I have a very complex command.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt < /dev/zero | base64
```

I looked at the node.js documentation and saw that pipe operator translates as two distinct spawn command([here, second example](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)). But there is nothing about "<" operator and I have no idea how to translate this nested command to a spawn statement. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Basicly wrap your command or commands into a bash script(.sh file) and then spawn that file with bash command.

For example:

```
rnd.sh file
--------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env bash

openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt < /dev/zero | base64
```

spawn that script in your node.js script and then run

```
rnd.js file
--------------------------
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const sp = spawn('bash', [__dirname + '/rnd.sh']);

sp.stdout.on('data', function(data){
// process stdout
}
```